# sending an post request in express.JS using mongoose ,data is not saving in the database

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

My HTML Code

```
<body>
    <form action="/contact" method="POST" id="contact">
        <div class="form">
            <div><input type="text" name="myname" placeholder="Type your name" required></div>
            <div><input type="text" name="city" placeholder="City" required></div>
            <div><input type="number" name="number" placeholder="Type your phone number" required></div>
            <div><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="ex:mohd53635@gmail.com" required></div>
            <div><input type="number" name="age" placeholder="Age" min="17" max="40" required></div>
            <div> Male<input type="radio" name="gender" id="male">Female <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female"></div>
            <button>Submit</button>
            <button type="reset">Reset</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

sending an post request with mongoose but data is not saving in database
I don't even getting error...

JavaScript modules:-

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { ejson } = require("ejs");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const path = require('path')
const fs = require("fs");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")
const { urlencoded } = require("express");
const port = 5000;
const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
```

//middlewares

```
app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../static")));
app.use('/static', express.static('static'))
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/static'));
```

//HTTP GET Requests:-

```
app.get('/index.html', function(req, res) {
    res.status(200).render(__dirname + '/index.html');
})
app.get('/contact.html', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/contact.html')
});
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
```

//Server

```
app.listen(port, () => {
    // console.log(`The Server Has Been Started On Port ${port}`)
});
```

//MongoDb Mongoose

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/moonform', { 
    useNewUrlParser: true, 
    useUnifiedTopology: true 
});
let db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function() {
    console.log("We are connected");
```

//Mongoose Schema:-

```
const moonSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    myname: String,
    number: Number,
    email: String,
    city: String,
    age: Number,
    gender: String
});
```

//Mongoose Model

```
let moon = mongoose.model('moon', moonSchema);
```

//Post Request

```
app.post('/contact', (req, res) => {
    let myData = new moon(req.body)
    myData.save().then((err, myData) => {
            res.send("This item has been saved to the database")
        })
        .catch(() => {
            res.status(400).send("item was not saved to the databse")
        });
});
```

//Mongoose Find

```
moon.find({ name: "moonform" }, function(err, myData) {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    console.log(moon)
});
```

Comment: please paste your code along with the question instead of images.

Comment: thanku for your feedback i edited my question and aded the Both code(HTML,,JS) in it and i am still searching for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well i finally figured out my problem that only thing that is missing in the code was..

```
app.use(express.urlencoded());
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Just try this.

```
//don't forget to wrap this inside async function
const result=await moon.find({});
console.log(result)
```

If this still gives an error that means your `req.body` might be empty

Comment: Sry but That didn't resolve the problem I'm still getting empty data....like. {_id: 60c1e5f2ad38233510a34585,__v: 0}.

Comment: buddy that moon.find() code is only for to use terminal as shell it does not affect the code until it has error even if i delete that moon.find() code my programe will work fine but then i have need to use windows powershell